# In an unordered list how can I align the text to the centre in the second column only?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, Age & 51 should be centered, the remainder aligned left.

```css
.munitionsvictims {
  list-style-type: none; /* 1841 census pages*/
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.munitionsvictims li {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.munitionsvictims p {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

.munitionsvictims p + p {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="munitionsvictims">
  <li>
    <p>Name</p>
    <p>Age</p>
    <p>Address</p>
    <p>Comment</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Thomas Allen</p>
    <p>51</p>
    <p>Charles Street Ashton Under Lyne</p>
    <p>Labourer at Works</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </li>

  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By centered do you mean center of div. Or just left by some pixels

Comment: DO 2 thing, 1 share your HTML Code, 2 The final output image would also be great

Comment: Well I only entered two rows of HTML for brevity.

The third row has a number with a single digit, which I wish to display centred when viewed  under the 51 . If anything it needs to go right a few pixels. As can be seen the 6 looks to be under the 5 of 51 which is not what I want.                                 Thomas Allen 51 Charles Street Ashton Under Lyne Labourer at Works  
Edwin Bibby 6 Bollington Street Ashton Under Lyne Taken to hospital with head injuries and died on Admission

Comment: See my Answer. Hope this helps :) You may adjust the margin-left as per your requirement. Increase or decrease. There are a lots of possibilites.

Comment: I edited the fiddle in my answer to align center only the second column, check it out, i hope it meets your needs :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using `:nth-child`

> The :nth-child selector allows you to select one or more elements
> based on their source order, according to a formula.

check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Naderial/1szj09q2/10/)** for your case.

[read more about `:nth-child` here.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

Comment: I guess I must have done it wrong as nothing seems to happen.```.munitionsvictims {
    list-style-type:none;      
 display:table;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
}

.munitionsvictims li {
    display:table-row;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
}.munitionsvictims li:nth-child(2) { 
    text-align:center;
}```

Comment: @AlbertMaytonn, check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Naderial/1szj09q2/